# Using Espresso to click on a webview with href

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, android-espresso

I have an html webpage which has a link something as follows.

```
<a id='click_link' href='path_to_page.html' target='_blank'>Click</a>
```

Using espresso I want to check if the link works from the Android webview. I used all the following method and also the XPATH link to click it from Android Espresso. Nothing works.

`onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.LINK_TEXT,"Click")).perform(webScrollIntoView());`

`onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,"click_link")).perform(webClick());`

But if I remove the `target='_blank'`, then it works. Is there any way to fix it from Espresso. I want the `target='_blank'` there.

Comment: Any news on this topic? Facing the same behaviour.

Comment: @YuriiTsap no luck with it. were you able to solve it ?